# seeing UI distortion

Tags: gmail

[image]

The inbox is looking distorted and has a funny image on the screen

Answer (score 1):

Those are simply "broken image" icons. Something is preventing your browser from getting the icons for each of those images. Perhaps a proxy setting, or a transient network issue, or something similar. Try a different browser and/or network.